# Segmentation Fault at ros::NodeHandle nh("node_name")

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello there,

I am facing a weird issue of getting a segmentation fault right in the second line of main function. Immediately after

```
ros::init(argc,argv,"node_name");
ros::NodeHandle nh("node_name");
```

Getting segmentation at NodeHandle function. The following is the back trace of the callstack where exception has occured.

```
Thread 1 "removed" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff750ec15 in ros::names::validate(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&) () from /opt/ros/noetic/lib/libroscpp.so
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff750ec15 in ros::names::validate(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&) () at /opt/ros/noetic/lib/libroscpp.so
#1  0x00007ffff753d8a2 in ros::NodeHandle::resolveName(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, bool) const () at /opt/ros/noetic/lib/libroscpp.so
#2  0x00007ffff753f5d5 in ros::NodeHandle::initRemappings(std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > const&) () at /opt/ros/noetic/lib/libroscpp.so
#3  0x00007ffff7540a1e in ros::NodeHandle::NodeHandle(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > const&) ()
    at /opt/ros/noetic/lib/libroscpp.so
#4  0x00005555555e216d in main(int, char**) (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe1e8) at /removed/src/main.cpp:6
```

Please help in troubleshooting this issue.

Ros Version: ROS1 Noetic

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/410039/segmentation-fault-at-ros::nodehandle-nh(%22node_name%22)/) by [shouvik1984](https://answers.ros.org/users/109848/shouvik1984/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2022-11-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like there is an issue with using

```
#pragma pack(1)
```

for one of the include files I was using for several structures in it. Once they were removed the sigsev is removed. However this needs further investigation on why is this happening

Regards
Shouvik

---

Originally posted by [shouvik1984](https://answers.ros.org/users/109848/shouvik1984/) with karma: 28 on 2022-12-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-12-03**:
A likely explanation would be you're changing the in-memory layout of `struct`s. Since you are using a binary distribution of `roscpp`, which wasn't compiled with that particular setting for padding/packing, you've introduced an ABI incompatibility. `SEGFAULT`s are one of the many things which can then happen.

If you need to override padding/packing settings for specific `struct`s, limit the setting to just those data types. Do not set it globally, especially not before you `#include` other headers.